# How to do a table with multicolumn in Latex?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have tried to do a table with multicolumn in LaTex but it doesn't work.
Here is my Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabu}{|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]c}
\tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
\multicolumn{8}{|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]}{\colorbox{yellow}{All Data}} \\ 
\tabucline[1.5pt]{-} 
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
\tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
Stepp 1 & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
\tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
Mean Value & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
\hline 
Standard\-deviation & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
\tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
%\end{adjustbox}
\normalsize
\caption{gesamt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And that's the result of the code:

[image: Result of the current Code]

But I want, that it looks like that:

[image: how it has to look]

Could someone help me to reach this, please? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are using the `tabu` package, which sadly isn't supported any more. But it would be easier to help if you provided a complete code, not just a snippet.

Comment: But this is the complete code of the table and not a snippet.

Comment: "Complete code" means from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, including the necessary packages (and only those). As I said, I believe you are using the `tabu` package, but this is only a guess, since *you haven't shown the code*.

Comment: This code is an excerpt from a work, which contains about 60 pages. I did not want to write the complete code here. 
The packages are: adjustbox, array, multirow, multicol, tabu, xcolor

Comment: I don't think  your preamble is 60 pages long. Can't you post an excerpt of your preamble (only the necessary packages)?

Comment: I have updated my question and now everything necessary is there.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) instead of the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines={1.5pt},vlines={1.5pt},cells={c},row{1}={yellow}}
\SetCell[c=8]{c} All Data & & & & & & & \\ 
                    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
Stepp 1             & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
Mean Value          & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
Standard-deviation  & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With a regular `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow}\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{All Data} \\ \hline 
                   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
Stepp 1            & • & • & • & • & • & • & •  \\ \hline
Mean Value         & • & • & • & • & • & • & •  \\ \hline
Standard deviation & • & • & • & • & • & • & •  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip


\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|l|}{All Data} \\ \hline 
                   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  \\ \hline
Stepp 1            & • & • & • & • & • & • & •  \\ \hline
Mean Value         & • & • & • & • & • & • & •  \\ \hline
Standard deviation & • & • & • & • & • & • & •  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,rules/width=1pt]{cccccccc}
\Block[fill=yellow]{1-8}{All Data} \\ 
                    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
Stepp 1             & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
Mean Value          & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
Standard-deviation  & • & • & • & • & • & • & • \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image]